# Best drivers backup (and maybe update) software 

Tags: windows, backup, drivers, updates

What are best drivers backup (and maybe update) software?

Some of this software do not seem to be good enough to trust...

Comment: I don’t trust driver-backup software. A driver-update app is simple enough; it checks the driver version and compares it to what the latest is, optionally downloading a new one. Backups however require somehow knowing exactly what is involved and part of the driver. That means the driver-backup-app needs to be able to either know (manually including in a database) or determine *all* of the files, registry entries, file-edits, services, and so on that the driver contains, uses, and installs. For some devices that is easy enough, but a lot of the time, that’s beyond any software I’ve ever seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Double Driver](http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm)** is a very simple and useful tool which not only allows you to view all the drivers installed on your system but also allows you to backup, restore, save and print all chosen drivers simply and reliably.

[image]

Double Driver is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Driver Genius](http://www.driver-soft.com/) in the past. Clones all of your drivers into a single executable installation. The only downside is that it's not free.

Some Free Alternatives:

- [DriverBackup!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/)
- [DriverMax](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/)