# How can I backup my windows XP drivers?

Tags: windows, backup, drivers, installation, restore

I've got a new (well, used) laptop.  I wish to format and reinstall the windows OS on it.  On the machine I've got several drivers which I would like to transport to the new machine, but I don't have the original drivers CD's.

Is there a (FREE) software that can backup my drivers, and then later let me reinstall them on the new windows installation?

Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/q/40403/3760

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I go about backing up/saving installed device drivers in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists specialized software for tasks just like that. [DriverMax](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/) being one of an examples (but "google: backup drivers" reveals more).

I have not used it, so alas, I cannot tell how well it performs.

Comment: I should have added the word free on my question.  Thanks.

Comment: DriverMax is an excellent program (mostly), and it is free.  I used it successfully though two reinstalls on two different machines.  it works! :)