# How to Save Current Drivers before Updating?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I’m been losing my internet connection about once a day and one suggestion was to delete the driver and reinstall the new driver from Intel. Okay I can do that, but what happens if the new driver is worse than the old one? Where would I find the original driver for my system to reinstall it?

Just clarify, I’m looking for a way to save copies of a driver on my system (not just the Network Adapters) before I update a driver. I just gave the system to myself for a Christmas present and I don’t want to screw it up!

It’s a ASUS Z170-A motherboard with an i7 6700k 4.GHz/4.2GHz running Windows 10 64bit.

Ran the Intel Driver Update Utility and got NO DRIVERS DETECTED!

This [2009 thread](https://superuser.com/questions/40403/) suggested something called Double Drivers, from a Google Search it looks it hasn’t been updated since 2014.  The second program Driver Genius, is supposed to support Windows 10.  Unfortunately, it has such horrible reviews I am not about to load on my machine.

**Edit:**  Double Drivers worked!  Here are a couple screen shots:

Backup program results screen shot:
[image]

Download of the program results screen shot, I used DD.exe:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double Driver is exactly what you are looking for.

However, the download link on the authors webpage does not seem to work.   I found this version over at Major Geeks

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/double_driver.html

Download and run the application.   By default, the program will auto select all of the drivers you need to have your computer function properly.

When the application opens, click Backup > Scan Current System to scan your system for drivers.    After Double Drivers scans your system, click Backup Now and select a location to save your drivers to.   I would recommend putting them on a thumb drive or something if you are planning on reinstalling your operating system, otherwise you will end up erasing them when you go to format your hard drive (if you plan on doing a full reinstall of windows).

Comment: Did you verify it works with Windows 10 (as per the OPs concern)? It looks like it may not even work with Windows 8/8.1 ("Requires: Win7/Vista/2K/XP"

Comment: I ran it using Windows 10.  I added a couple of screen shots to show results.  One caveat, I haven’t tested re-installing the driver.  I just wanted some hope for a Plan B if downloading new drivers failed.

Comment: Yes I tested it with Windows 10.