# Is there a way to transfer network card driver onto sd card?

Tags: windows-vista, network-adapter

Is there a way to transfer network card driver onto sd card so I can reformat my computer and put driver back?

It's an older machine running Windows Vista Busniess.

HP Compaq dx3400

I can't seem to find the drivers online.

[image]

Comment: There is the tool "DoubleDriver" which can save driver from your running system. See https://superuser.com/a/1021939/471143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, no one should be using Windows Vista as it is [out of support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22882/windows-vista-end-of-support).  If you continue to use Windows Vista now that support has ended, your computer will still work but it might become more vulnerable to security risks and viruses.

Secondly, the HP Compaq DX3400 did not come with Vista.  It only came with Windows 7 32 or 64 bit.  That is why it isnt listed.

You can try to install the Windows 7 Realtek RTL8171E Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver, or look for the Vista version on the internet.